Can I override Authorize attribute in ASP.NET and how?
So i have basic web app created with ASP.NET Core. I have two areas , one normal and one administrator. In administrator area i have DistilleryController which inherits my base Admin controller:
[Area(AdminArea)]
[Authorize(Roles = Administrator)]
public class AdminBaseController : Controller
{

}

I decided to have one Action Method in DistilleryController which will show info for all users , not only Admin.
This is it:
[Route("Distillery/Details/{id}")]
[HttpGet]
[Authorize(Roles = $"{WhiskyExpert},{UserRole}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int id)
{

    return View();
}

And this is the link that will send here:
 <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Distillery", new { id = Model.DistilleryId })">@Model.DistilleryName</a>

The thing is i always get AccesDenied , when i try to reach this method with other role than Administrator, even when i overrided [Authorize] attribute. How to make it work ?
Thanks in advance.
I tried with overriding [Authorize], but still the same result. Btw if i use [AllowAnonymous] it works , but i dont want Guests to be able to open this page.
